Handle Entity classes with Symfony Validator component
I'm trying to use symfony/validator outside of Symfony by just installing composer require symfony/validator (vemphasized text7.1)
Following this guide https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/validator.html
I now have:
$validator = Validation::createValidator();
$violations = $validator->validate($someName, [
    new Length(['min' => 10]),
    new NotBlank(),
]);

This validation works fine.
But I would like validation like in this guide:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation.html
So that I can validate something like this:
// src/Entity/Author.php
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Author
{
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    public string $name;
}

When I now try to validate it $violations is always 0 even if the name is null
    $author = new Author();
    $author->name = null;
    $validator = Validation::createValidator();
    $violations = $validator->validate($author);

The documentation isn't very clear on this but it looks like the standalone version is incapable of handling a class like this.
Is something like this possible with the standalone version?

After battling this one for hours, and trying various solutions provided online as well as @Arno van Oordt's answer which did not work for me, I figured it out and it was so simple.
<?php

namespace App\Domain\Entities;

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Slug
{
    #[Assert\NotBlank]
    #[Assert\Type('string')]
    private string $slug;
    
    public function setSlug(): string
    {
        return $this->slug;
    }

}


This is what worked for me
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
    ->enableAttributeMapping()
    ->getValidator();



$slug = new Slug();
$slug->setSlug('the_slug_string')

$validator->validate($slug);


The key that I was missing was ->enableAttributeMapping() that I had been missing.
So in your case it will look like this
$author = new Author();
$author->name = null;
$validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()
    ->enableAttributeMapping()
    ->getValidator();

$violations = $validator->validate($author);


LOL, I just noticed that you had asked and answered your own question, @Arno. I hope that this will help someone else.

Thanks, that was indeed what I was looking for!
Weird that this is nowhere to be found in the documentation :(

Turned out that creating function that does the same trick wasn't that hard to make:
function validateEntity($entity)
{
    $class = new ReflectionClass($entity);

    $validator = Validation::createValidator();

    $violations = [];
    $properties = $class->getProperties();
    foreach ($properties as $property) {
        $propertyName = $property->getName();
        $attributes = $property->getAttributes();
        $constraints = [];
        foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
            $constraints[] = $attribute->newInstance();
        }

        try {
            $value = $entity->$propertyName;
        }
        catch(Error $err) {
            $value = null;
        }
        $propertyViolations = $validator->validate($value, $constraints);
        if (count($propertyViolations)) {
            $violations[$propertyName] = $propertyViolations;
        }
    }
    return $violations;
}

Call it like
$author = new Author();
$violations = validateEntity($author);

I only needed it for simple entities so not sure if it works well for more complicated situations.
